# What is the counterpart for expression `?value1:value2` in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to know what the counterpart is in Ruby for this kind of expression:

```
var status=false;
var xx=new Obj(xx,status?"0":"1",status?"2":"3");
```

I tried the same in Ruby, but it seems that the syntax:

```
status?"23":nil
```

does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method names can end with question marks, so use more spaces:

```
status ? "23" : nil
```

Equivalently you could write:

```
("23" if status)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a space between `status` and `?`. Seems that it might get parsed as a method name `status?`. Also, don't terminate your sentences with semicolons. And don't use `var`.

```
x = status ? "0" : "1"
```